# How to check if username is allowed or not like twitter?

Tags: php

How to check if username is allowed or not like twitter:

```
Your username can only contain letters, numbers and '_'
```

i try something like this but it's not working:

```
if(preg_match("/^[\w.-]*$/", $username)){
   // Code
}
```

Comment: The regex you just deleted worked for me. I guess you have your logic back to front. You need to reject usernames which dont match, not ones which do

Comment: @miknik They shouldn't have defaced their original post, to which I rolled back to now.

Comment: The duplicate used to close the question with, contains the solution for this. All you need to do is replace the hyphen with an underscore. You can do that, can you? At the very least.

Comment: @miknik really thank you yes its working now using "/^[\w.-]*$/" but how to prevent using '-'?

Comment: Delete it from your regex expression. You have a - inside the square brackets

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$username = "this_is_username";

$username_control = preg_match("/^[a-z0-9_\d\S.]+$/", $username);

if($username_control === 1){
  // success
}else{
  // error
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not working with me, I edited my question i hope you understand me now.

Comment: ok. try again, i edited.

Comment: As per the documentation you should always use === for testing the return value of preg_match. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: thanks @miknik bug fixed..